# grep with indentation-based context

Tags: grep, indentation, utility

Is there a grep tool that shows context based on indentation? For each match, I would like to see all the most recent lines with a lower indent level, but skip all the lines at the same indent level in between. Example:

```
$ contextgrep rstrip pep8.py
class Checker(object):
    def check_logical(self):
        if self.verbose >= 2:
            print(self.logical_line[:80].rstrip())
```

Comment: go write one as you illustrated in the code block, ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [blog post](http://limpet.net/mbrubeck/2010/01/12/outline-grep.html) about a [literal Haskell implementation](https://github.com/mbrubeck/outline-grep/blob/master/OutlineGrep.lhs) of "outline grep".